# How to get Satuday's date of previous month in SQL Server? Can someone help me with this query?

Tags: sql-server, dayofweek, monthcalendar

Suppose now we are in September, I want output of the last Saturday date in the previous month, August, where 28-08-2021 falls under last Saturday of previous month in SQL Server

Comment: Create - statically preferred or dynamically - a calendar table. It is a basic, common, and frequent need in SQL of any dialect.

Comment: It should be dynamic...No hardcoding please

Answer (score 0):

First, let's talk about how to get the beginning of this month. There are a multiple ways, I find `DATEFROMPARTS()` the most intuitive (see [Simplify Date Period Calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)):

```
DECLARE @FirstOfMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);

SELECT @FirstOfMonth;

-- result:
-- 2021-09-01
```

Now, the last Saturday in the *previous* month must be between 1 and 7 days before the first of this month. So we can generate a sequence of 7 consecutive numbers, and subtract those days from the first of the month, like this:

```
DECLARE @FirstOfMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);

SELECT @FirstOfMonth;

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT n + 1 FROM n WHERE n < 7
)
SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, -n, @FirstOfMonth) FROM n;

/* result:

2021-08-31
2021-08-30
2021-08-29
2021-08-28
2021-08-27
2021-08-26
2021-08-25 */
```

To determine what a Saturday is, you either need to rely on `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date)` - which in turn is affected by `SET DATEFIRST`, or you need to rely on `DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)` - which in turn is affected by `SET LANGUAGE`. I will err toward language being more stable (English), so:

```
DECLARE @FirstOfMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);

SELECT @FirstOfMonth;

;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT n + 1 FROM n WHERE n < 7
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -n, @FirstOfMonth)
  FROM n
)
SELECT LastMonthLastSaturday = d
  FROM d
  WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d) = 'Saturday';

-- result:
-- 2021-08-28
```

But that is a subjective call - if you can't rely on one of those, get a calendar table, then it's simply something like:

```
SELECT LastMonthLastSaturday = MAX(TheDate) 
  FROM dbo.Calendar 
  WHERE TheDayOfWeekName = 'Saturday' 
  AND TheDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d60b1e9f430bec8d5caae57381e034e)..

```
select *, datename(weekday, pmlsat), dateadd(week, 1, pmlsat)
from
(
  select _date, 
    --last saturday of previous month
    dateadd(day, -datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst, eomonth(_date, -1)))%7, eomonth(_date, -1)) as pmlsat
  from
  (
    select top(100) dateadd(month, row_number() over(order by @@spid), '20141215') as _date
    from sys.all_objects
  ) as d
) as p
order by _date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME

SET @date1='2021-8-31'

WHILE Day(@date1) >= 1
  BEGIN
      
      IF (SELECT Datename(weekday, @date1)) = 'Saturday'
        BREAK

      SET @date1=Dateadd(dd, -1, @date1)

      CONTINUE
  END

SELECT Datename(weekday, @date1)                  AS 'Datename',
       (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @date1, 23)) AS 'DATE'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).